# LLM RAG with Agent

Tags: python, large-language-model

I was trying the application code in the [link](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/conversational_retrieval_agents).

I am using the following Llang Chain version

langchain                                0.0.327
langchain-community                      0.0.2
langchain-core                           0.1.0

Getting the following error:

```
Entering new AgentExecutor chain...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RAGWithAgent.py", line 54, in <module>
    result = agent_executor({"input": "hi, im bob"})
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 310, in __call__
    raise e
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py", line 304, in __call__
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 1146, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py", line 933, in _take_next_step
    output = self.agent.plan(
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\openai_functions_agent\base.py", line 104, in plan
    predicted_message = self.llm.predict_messages(
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 650, in predict_messages
    return self(messages, stop=_stop, **kwargs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 600, in __call__
    generation = self.generate(
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 349, in generate
    raise e
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 339, in generate
    self._generate_with_cache(
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 492, in _generate_with_cache
    return self._generate(
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\openai.py", line 357, in _generate
    return _generate_from_stream(stream_iter)
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\base.py", line 57, in _generate_from_stream
    for chunk in stream:
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\openai.py", line 326, in _stream
    for chunk in self.completion_with_retry(
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\openai.py", line 299, in completion_with_retry
    return _completion_with_retry(**kwargs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 289, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
  File "\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 379, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 314, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "\lib\site-packages\tenacity\__init__.py", line 382, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\langchain\chat_models\openai.py", line 297, in _completion_with_retry
    return self.client.create(**kwargs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\chat_completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\openai\api_resources\abstract\engine_api_resource.py", line 155, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
  File "\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 299, in request
    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
  File "\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 710, in _interpret_response
    self._interpret_response_line(
  File "\lib\site-packages\openai\api_requestor.py", line 775, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: functions

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I used Azure LLM instead openAI.
FAISS was not working for me so used Chroma Vector Store.

Following is my code:

```
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter

from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import create_retriever_tool
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import create_conversational_retrieval_agent

from langchain.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings

import os

AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY = ""
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY

loader = TextLoader(r"Toward a Knowledge Graph of Cybersecurity Countermeasures.txt")
documents = loader.load()
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)


# create the open-source embedding function
embedding_function = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-mpnet-base-v2")

current_directory = os.path.dirname("__file__")

# load it into Chroma and save it to disk
db = Chroma.from_documents(chunks, embedding_function, collection_name="groups_collection",
                           persist_directory=r"\rag_with_agent_chroma_db")

retriever = db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 5})

tool = create_retriever_tool(
    retriever,
    "search_state_of_union",
"Searches and returns documents regarding the state-of-the-union.",
)
tools = [tool]

llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
    deployment_name='gtp35turbo',
    model_name='gpt-35-turbo',
    openai_api_key=AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    openai_api_version='2023-03-15-preview',
    openai_api_base='https://azureft.openai.azure.com/',
    openai_api_type='azure',
    streaming=True,
    verbose=True
)

agent_executor = create_conversational_retrieval_agent(llm, tools, verbose=True, remember_intermediate_steps=True,
                                                       memory_key="chat_history")

result = agent_executor({"input": "hi, im bob"})

print(result["output"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried multiple including the answers mentioned above. But did not work. I even tried to degrade, and upgrade llm version.

Finally, the following code to initialize the agent worked for me with the current version of llm

```
conversational_agent = initialize_agent(
        agent=AgentType.CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, 
        tools=tools,
        llm=llm,
        max_iterations=10,
        handle_parsing_errors=True,
        early_stopping_method="generate",
        memory=memory, 
        verbose=True,
        
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the version of the backend API used to `2023-09-01-preview` :

```py
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
    deployment_name='gtp35turbo',
    model_name='gpt-35-turbo',
    openai_api_key=AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    openai_api_version='2023-09-01-preview',
    openai_api_base='https://azureft.openai.azure.com/',
    openai_api_type='azure',
    streaming=True,
    verbose=True
)
```

From the  comments in this [Github issue](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/11478#issuecomment-1836216115)

Answer (score 0):

Your code's error likely stems from compatibility issues between Azure and LangChain. The 'unrecognized request argument' error points to a mismatch in expected parameters, such as `"openai_api_version=2023-07-01-preview"` for Azure. To resolve this, copy the correct parameters from your Azure Chat Playground in Azure OpenAI Studio.

If you are looking for more controlled generations, consider using `nextpy.ai.engine`, which offers greater control than standard prompting and chaining.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).